# PHP: upload files (vids) directly to S3

Tags: php, ajax, video, file-upload, amazon-s3

I'm looking for examples (maybe on Github, blog, or elsewhere) that demonstrate how to upload files (videos) directly from a php http post form to AWS S3. The main requirement is to see the progress of the upload in action and trigger a response when complete (without reloading the page). jQuery File Upload Plugin could be a good solution, do you know of any code examples that do this? The files (videos) will be up to 1gb in size, so propose a different method if you think this won't work well.

Answer (score 1):

You have checked [this](http://aws.amazon.com/articles/1434) out, right?

Sadly, there's no progress involved by default. Probably you should do it yourself using AWS serverside API and ajax polling (or websockets), which would add workload for your server, though.

[Here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/HLTrackProgressMPUDotNet.html) is a C# example of how to track the Multipart Upload Progress.

Otherwise you could go for a client-side approach with the [Javascript SDK](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/guide/browser-examples.html#Uploading_a_local_file_using_the_File_API).